# unable to retrieve POST data after submiting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**Hello everyone,**

I'm trying to send some (POST) data using jQuery to PHP file but I'm getting "Undefined index" errors every time I submit my form.

**upload.html**

```
<form id="formx" action="upload.php" onSubmit="return false" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<b>Upload new image</b> <br />
            <input type="button" id="get_file" value="Grab file">
            <div id="customfileupload">Select a file</div>
            <input type="file" id="file_input" name="uploadedfile">
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload image" />
        <div id="status"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**upload.js**

```
var options = { 
        target: '#status',  
        type: "POST",
        data: "dir=music",
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit, 
        uploadProgress: OnProgress,
        success:       afterSuccess,
        error: function(hr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            status.html("<font color='red'> ERROR: unable to upload file.</font>"+thrownError);
        },
        resetForm: true  
    }; 

 $('#formx').submit(function(event) { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);             
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

echo "->".$_POST['dir'];

?>
```

It's obvious that I'm not sending the data correctly. I have tried changing the dataType , but still not getting the desired result. I would really appreciate if someone could advise me on  how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Comment: Your form has no inputs with name `dir`. What exactly are you trying to retrieve from your form?

Comment: Are you able to on console request has successfullt sent to php?

Comment: @slider , I want a custom variable to be sent as part of the submit function ..

Comment: `data: { key1 : value1, key2, value2, ... }`.

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL I can see no errors in my browser's console. Although the Apache throws this error "  Undefined index: dir in ..." .

Comment: @moonwave99 , Thanks, it works like a charm now. 

**data: { "dir":"music" },**

Comment: I mean, check your network tab in console, can you see ajax request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending the data as a JavaScript object and add the url that you want to send to. Your script will **not** take the URL from the form attribute by default.

```
data: {
    "dir": "music"
},
url: "upload.php"
```

Taken from jQuery documentation

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. **Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs.** If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
>   (described below).

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

the dataType parameter is actually for the data you get from the php file it does not relate to the data you send.

That being said, I think there should be a url element in the options array that should send the data to upload.php so you would have something like this:

```
var options = { 
        target: '#status',
        url: '/path/to/upload.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: "dir=music",
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit, 
        uploadProgress: OnProgress,
        success:       afterSuccess,
        error: function(hr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            status.html("<font color='red'> ERROR: unable to upload file.</font>"+thrownError);
        },
        resetForm: true  
    };
```

Comment: I guess it automatically takes this parameter from the form, or does it not?